# Check if package name changed

Tags: java, android, apk, reverse-engineering

I want to protect my APK from reverse engineering, by showing `Toast`, or do something if package name changed, now if package changed the app will stop working.

```
if (getPackageName().compareTo("com.apk.example") != 0) {

    String error = null; 
    error.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: what is the question, you need to be more specific

Comment: i want to check if my app package name is equal to one i give above, or is not, to avoid stealing my APK from play store. as you see if my app's package name changed , it will stop the app from launching ! i hope u understand.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, as the reverse engineer can see where the app crashes and can simply remove this if-statement. Instead, modify the app so it crashes somewhere else. Also, make sure you obfuscate the package name

Comment: @ZUNJAE Really ? how can he see the error ?? I'm using APK Tool .

Comment: @zomba that thing is called logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check both your package name and application id to make sure your app haven't been tampered with:

```
String yourPackageName = "com.apk.example"; // android package name
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

// can be different from your package name if you're using flavor
// in app.build.gradle, 
String yourApplicationId = "com.apk.example"; 

if(packageName.equals(yourPackageName) && BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equals(yourApplicationId)) {
   // no problem here
} else {
   // app is tampered, do something
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and get tis error :    `Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig`

Comment: @zomba: Sorry, there's typo: `Build.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` it should be `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`